# OpenStreetMap/GeoServer fill polygon color on user interaction

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, census, user-interface

I'm trying to build a system to show census tract on map. I used [this](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-censusmap/) example to import the census tract TIGER shapefile into DB, flatten the data on the column I need and managed to show a map with census tract using GeoServer, OpenLayers and OSM.

Now I need to add interaction where a user can select a census tract and be able to change the fill color. The example I followed creates a `ol.Layer.Image` layer which, I think, won't work here. I tried using a vector layer with a GeoJSON source from GeoServer but the browser is crashing trying to load 74K rows through JSON. I'm looking at vector tile example [here](https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/vectortile/) but it doesn't cover dynamic style change from user interaction.

Is it possible to use OpenLayers/GeoServer with what I'm trying to do?

I'm new to these technologies and this is my first experiment with GIS.

Comment: Why is it loading 74k, it's too much to be displayed. geoserver can serve data for the current bbox only, which should reduce the data volume

Comment: The 74k records comes from the number of census tracts in the US. When creating the layer in GeoServer, I selected 'Compute from data' option for bounding box and left default values which covers the whole US.  I think I can restrict the number of rows by using the 'maxFeatures' qs [link] 
 (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) but the tracts are all over the place instead of zoom-in around one focal point. But I'm not sure if using Vector layer is the right approach for user interaction to fill color of a polygon.